# Turn a static table to dynamic

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula (without lambda function by preference) that could turn a static table to dynamic table.

For example, Column B contains raw data. I'm looking for a formula in D3, which contains `B3` or e.g., `B3:B1000` (to largely cover the area), such that it returns a dynamic array which is all the data below `B3` until a blank cell. Then, in another cell, formulas like `=D3#` spill well.

[image]

Does anyone have a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=B3:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(B:B="")*(ROW(B:B)>3),0)-1)` works without sequence, so compatible for Excel prior to office 365. (To be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter` then) also this is non volatile (OFFSET recalculates at every change in sheet).

Comment: If you have a small file it will hardly be noticable, but the larger the file and the more volatile formulas, the slower your Excel gets.

Comment: It works, thank you. Did not know that we could write `B3:INDEX...`

Comment: You could even use `INDEX():INDEX()`

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use `INDEX`, `SEQUENCE`, `XMATCH`, and `ISBLANK`.

```
=INDEX(B3:B1000,SEQUENCE(XMATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(B3:B1000))-1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

Formula in `D3` is:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,1,0,MATCH(0,COUNTIFS(B$3:B$1000,B$3:B$1000),0)-1,1)
```

- `MATCH` in combination with `COUNTIFS` is used to determine the position of the first blank cell
- `OFFSET` delivers the rows from the beginning to the blank cell.

[image]